# recessed led worked fine for 3 months but today turned on today and its blinking on and off; not on a dimmer and not using a 3-way switch

Tags: led

help. For the past 3 months my recessed kitchen light has worked fine. Controlled by standard switch. Not a dimmer and not a 3-way switch. Today I turn on and started blinking on and off about 1 sec each. Not related to any other appliances coming on and off. No changes to house electrical recently. There is no insulation around the light either. The light fixture/unit cost about $70 from home depot. It screwed into the old can light socket for easy install.

Comment: Have you tried the bulb in a different socket?

Comment: Please [merge your guest and registered accounts](/help/merging-accounts), which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

I left it off a few days and even removed and tested on anther circuit but same blinking problem. Took back to HD given replacement...defective device. Thanks for your suggestions however.

Comment: Please [merge your guest and registered accounts](/help/merging-accounts), which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

### It's toasty up there...

This sounds like the classic behavior of a recessed fixture that is overheating and thus cycling on its thermal limiter.  Try replacing the bulb with a smaller one, or one that has better heatsinking (doesn't get as hot).

Comment: Yes, the problem may cure itself this winter. Try also at 7am when the house is at its coolest.

Answer (score 0):

I have been installing led retrofits in office fixtures for several years , I find 2 failures at this time the light starts flashing or will not light at all in both cases the driver has failed in every one of the fixtures that I tore apart and examined. I have lost or had failures at about 10% of the medium priced lamps / fixtures with 3-5 year warranties and less than 1% of high priced fixtures. I have found that most all the drivers are made in Taiwan or China and the only way to get longer lasting fixtures is to look for DLC listing and a longer warranty.